# Separating data and test settings in QTests

Tags: qt, unit-testing

I am currently using following pattern when creating tests with `QTest`.

1. One test class per production class.
2. If a class has some 'global' setting run the test class multiple times with each such setting.
3. Each production class method has one test method.
4. Each test method has `_data` method.
5. Each `_data` method specify **settings** and **data** to be used and names the cases.

This last point somewhat bothers me because I am not passing just data but also data to be used for initialising that particular test. Sometimes it looks weird and even though my tests are short they are not all that intuitive because of the initialisation logic.

The alternative pattern I know of is to split each test method (breaking my rule #3) based on this initialisation needs. On one hand it would eliminate a lot of `_data` test methods but it would also make the test classes much bigger and no longer easily relatable to the production class (the naming would help though). Most google tests are written like this.

Another alternative would be to use global state of the object much like I treat global settings. If the object is either valid or invalid then it would not be part of each `_data` method but rather setting of the test class that would run in either configuration.

My main concern is maintainability. With my current approach I sometimes struggle to understand the nuances of the settings I pass to the tests and I need some sensible way to separate them and not to burden myself even more by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For global settings you run the test class multiple times, so IMHO doing the same for local settings doesn't really "violate" your rule #3, it is more an extension of rule #2.

Alternatively you could make the initialization routine another thing that is part of the test data.

Something like

```
private slots:
    void someMethodTest_data()
    {
        QTest::addColumn<QByteArray>("settings");
        //....
        QTest::addRow("case1") << "settings1" << ....
    }

    void someMethodTest()
    {
        Q_FETCH(QByteArray, settings);

        const QByteArray initMethod = QTest::currentTestFuntion() + "_init_" + settings;
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, initMethod.constData(), Qt::DirectConnect);

        // commence test 
    }

protected slots:
    void someMethodTest_init_settings1();
```

Comment: This is actually what I am leaning towards as well. Nice trick with invoking the method composed of the stuff recieved from `_data`!